# Remove sub menu items

Tags: wordpress, menu, menuitem, submenu

I want to remove a few sub menu items from the admin menu in WordPress. I have found the following which can remove certain sub menu items...

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adjust_the_wp_menu', 999 );
function adjust_the_wp_menu() {
  $page = remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'widgets.php' );
}
```

...but what if it is not a standard php such as "themes.php?page=custom-header" that I would like removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Add code in your function.php**

```
Remove "themes.php?page=custom-header" option using this code.


function remove_twentyeleven_options() {
    remove_custom_image_header();
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme','remove_twentyeleven_options', 100 );
```

Comment: Thanks, Ravi. That works for the custom header option, but there are others that I am trying to remove as well. Some of them are for woocommerce and other plugin related menu items.

Comment: which remove particular menu or submenu please define list.

Comment: edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product, edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_tag&post_type=product, edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_shipping_class&post_type=product, edit.php?post_type=product&page=woocommerce_attributes

Comment: where create taxonomy(product_tag)code in find 'show_ui' => true, replace 'show_ui' => false,

Comment: I don't quite understand your last comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Thanks to Ravi for pointing me in the right direction.

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_taxonomy_menu_pages', 999 );
function remove_taxonomy_menu_pages() {
    // remove products->categories
    register_taxonomy('product_cat', 
        'woocommerce_taxonomy_objects_product_cat', array('show_ui' => false)
    );
    // remove products->tags
    register_taxonomy('product_tag', 
        'woocommerce_taxonomy_objects_product_tag', array('show_ui' => false)
    );
    // remove products->shipping classes
    register_taxonomy('product_shipping_class', 
        'woocommerce_taxonomy_objects_product_shipping_class', array('show_ui' => false)
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_submenu_pages', 999 );
function remove_submenu_pages() {
    // remove products->attributes
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', 'woocommerce_attributes');
}
```

Comment: remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', 'product_attributes'); for removing the product attributes submenuitem

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share, that's how you can remove woocommerce submenu's

- Product Attributes
- Product Shipping Class

--

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_taxonomy_menu_pages', 999 );
function remove_taxonomy_menu_pages() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', 'product_attributes' );
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_shipping_class&post_type=product');
}
```