# Remove submenus from "Products" menu in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, customization

I have one problem with my WooCommerce. I want to customize a lot, and want this things.

I want to remove all submenus, and left only "Products" and "Add Product" submenus. Is this prossible?

Image> https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2056.png

Also is possible to remove "Shipping" label when admin add a product?

Image> https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVAHm.png

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I found one part of sollution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198264/woocommerce-removing-product-write-panel-tab but not found how to hide "Commision" tab yet.

Comment: Also found how to remove Products submenus. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703391/remove-sub-menu-items